# Fable: TLC - no mobs/respawn?

Tags: fable

I'm playing Fable: TLC and there are no enemies in the Old Graveyard Path, Lychfield Graveyard and Circle of Dead, why?

Actually there were enemies only when I was going to the prison to save my mother, then there were no mobs when I was coming back with her and looks like since that time there's no respawn at these locations at all.

At first I thought I have some quest active or something, but that's not that, I even killed Jack of Blades and still nothing.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Usually there aren't any mobs there, those that you encounter are sent there by Jack. Think of that area being like The Lookout Point.